# Couchbase Query with ORDER BY DESC and LIMIT is very slow

Tags: couchbase, sql++

```
select t.createdDate, t.createdDateTicks from ic_v10_mammoet t where t.type='asset' and t._sync.rev is not null ORDER BY t.createdDateTicks ASC  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The above query takes 6 seconds to return result and when I remove ORDER BY clause it take only 18 MS

```
select t.createdDate, t.createdDateTicks from ic_v10_mammoet t where t.type='asset' and t._sync.rev is not null LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I have an index on createdDateTicks and it is integer field.

I tried the workaround mentioned at [workaround](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/using-order-by-param-desc-in-n1ql-is-very-slow-5s/7489/5) as last comment but that do not work.

Can someone please advise?

Index is:`CREATE INDEX asset_createdDateTicks ON ic_v10_mammoet (createdDateTicks) WHERE type = 'asset'`

Plan [with](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2781659/planwithorderby.json) ORDER BY and Plan [without](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2781659/planwithoutorderby.json) ORDER BY

Comment: I don't see any way to create an index with ASC/DESC option either

Comment: Explain "does not work". No results? Error? Still slow? Slower?

Comment: Post your exact index and query for the workaround.

Comment: The workaround do not help in making query faster.

Comment: index, query and execution plan added to the message

Comment: The index and query you posted do not reflect the workaround. You need to post the index and query that use the workaround.

Comment: updated query and index link document to show it as per the workaround provided

Comment: I have actually changed the createdDateTicks to be negative on the document so I don't need to add - to the index and order by clause. Still the performance is same not sure how to handle. Total number of records are only 15000 and it is taking 5 seconds to fetch 10 records with ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Comment: If you changed the field to be negative, you should be using ORDER BY ... ASC. Not DESC. That is the idea of the workaround.

Comment: Yes I changed it to  ORDER BY ASC but it still take 5 s to return result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_neg_date ON docs( -createDateTicks ) WHERE type = 'asset';

SELECT t.createdDate, t.createdDateTicks
FROM docs AS t
WHERE t.type='asset' AND -t.createdDateTicks IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY -t.createdDateTicks ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: I had to force specify index to be used. Still I am stuck in performance with JOIN as I am discussing with you on couchbase forum